# Dynamic Django Application Creation Based On a SQL / CSV file

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-apps

Is there any django application that can create other apps merely based on a sql / csv file provided that a default template is found for the new applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use database introspection to create models from pre-existing tables. You can divide the models up into apps and fix the odd error it seems to produce now an again. It saves a heap of time when integrating with legacy databases.

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

More details:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/legacy-databases/

Apart from that I don't know of anything for CSV or SQL files and am not sure what you mean by "default template".